# Php FPM + Apache. Customize 404 for PHP files

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, mod-proxy

I have setup a small Apache instance and configured PHP with FPM. I am using the ProxyPassMatch directive.

Now, when FPM does not find the requested file, it will just print out "File not found" and quit, without using my custom error pages.

I have found no documentation around, about how to customize those error pages. Is there any tweak to the Proxy directives to handle errors? Or should I check that the file exists via a RewriteRule?

Maybe you already have an example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ProxyErrorOverride directive for that.
See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride